# create javascript code from obfuscated javascript code

Tags: javascript, obfuscation

I want to know is it possible to reproduce obfuscated javascript code(create javascript code from obfuscated javascript code).

I have some javascript code in my website. I want to prevent others to edit it. For that I user obfuscation. So I want to know, is it possible to create original javascript code from an obfuscated code.

Comment: Related: [Deobfuscating Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867027/deobfuscating-javascript)

Comment: I have some javascript code in my website. I want to obfuscate it, so I want to know is there any way to convert it to original code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a code formatter like [JavaScript beautifier](http://jsbeautifier.org/) to bring the code back into a more or less readable *structure*. It is impossible to re-build meaningful variable names from compressed ones, though, so in the end, it's not possible. And it's a good thing that it isn't - that's the point of obfuscating code, isn't it?

Answer (score 3):

It's fairly straightforward to turn the obfuscated code back into the effective javascript that runs - typically you just need to expand a bunch of `eval` calls.

The tricky part, as others have stated, is giving names to the variables so that you can work out what something like `v7 = a4.l2(h8, n1, p9)` means.  Something I've found helpful is to start from the "edges" (library calls that can't be renamed" and then rename things as helpfully as possible.  You'll often find that this knowledge then ripples through the code, making it easier to grasp the next layer down and give it a sensible name.

So for example, if you had some code like this:

```
z4 = "a";
o0 = "href"

...

pr = window.document;

...

q8 = pr.getElementByTagName(z4)[0];

...

function rr(o8, em)
{
   return o8.getAttribute(em);
};

...

y5 = rr(q8, o0);
```

Then the last line is initially impenetrable, but if you decide that `rr` could be called `getNamedAttribute`, rename `z4` as `LITERAL_A`, `o0` as `LITERAL_HREF` and `pr` as `document`; then we can see that `q8` is the result of `document.getElementByTagName(LITERAL_A)[0]`, so we might call it `firstAnchor`.  Then `q8 = getNamedAttribute(firstAnchor, LITERAL_HREF)` and all of a sudden it's clear it's the (string) target of the first hyperlink.

Since this transformation requires inference on behalf of the reader, it's not possible for this to be an automatic process (for *exactly* the same reason that a compiler won't warn you about inappropriate variable names).

Answer (score 0):

If you only have obfuscuated code and want to modify/make sense of it,  the only thing you can do is indent it properly so it's more readable, then start from the begining of the process and rename the functions and variables yourself trying to work out what the purpose and function of each is.  It's a time consuming and slow process and can be very tricky.