# Deobfuscate Javascript?

Tags: javascript, obfuscation, deobfuscation

I had my precious javascript obfuscated [here](http://www.javascriptobfuscator.com/). I THOUGHT I had saved a local version with my original code, but it turns out there is ONE line that is obfuscated on the local version.

I realize it completely destroys the point of obfuscating something if you deobfuscate it so easily, but it has to be possible. I tried the Firefox plugin to no avail. Is there any hope?

Comment: Try http://jsbeautifier.org with the *"Detect packers and obfuscators?"* option.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2867027/deobfuscating-javascript